# angular-ui-select2 nested ng-repeat not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-select2

I'd like to display a structure like

```
parent
-child1
--childOfChild1
-child2
```

inside select options using angular.

Using lists or other elements works great but when using select2 the result is each option displays a single hyphen like `- category`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/WhLCM/

Culprit:

`<select class="input-medium" ui-select2 ng-model="category" type="text" >
    <option ng-repeat="cat in categories" value="{{cat.name}}">
       <span ng-repeat="a in cat.ancestors">-</span>
       {{cat.name}}
    </option>
</select>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`span` is not allowed inside `option` element, so the inner `ng-repeat` never kicks in. You need to try something different, for example this: http://jsfiddle.net/WhLCM/18/